# CSS table height

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a problem doing the following in CSS (I want to avoid the extra javascript at page ready):
I have a table with 100 rows, it's size is bigger then the window.
I want to make the table height = winodw height, so that I can insert a scrollbar on the table. The reason for that is that I have to "navigating" divs arround the table(up and down) which I want to be visible when you scroll. It works perfect if I set the container's height to exact pixels, but using %, just spawns the table with a scroll on the page. Is it possible to do this in CSS without javascript?

So my current css for the table:

```
#mainTable{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

The thing is this does not give the same result as if I do `height=800px`, given that the window is 800px, since with % you get a scroll on the page and with px you get a scroll on the table.

Comment: yes , but we need to see your code, in jsfiddle

Comment: problem is it is huge... cause I'm using several extra libraries and other ppls css. I'll still post some more code to make it clear.

Comment: did you try overflow:scroll instead of auto..

Comment: Yep, still scroll is on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parameter_one = "http: //one.css";  //your css for table
var parameter_two = "http: //two.css"   //your css w/o table

if (window.height < somevalue) {
    load_me(parameter_one)
} else {
    load_me(parameter_two)
}

function load_me(file) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = file;
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: Why won't you use an @media instead (in css)?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do `width: 100%;` because it can sometimes go over the page length, you can try 90%, 80%, or even 70%, or an exact width, or you could try giving it like, `margin: 20px;` the height, I would just do an exact height like `height: 200px;` thats probably not the width you want but you know what I mean.

**OR**

you could do JavaScript like the last guy said. Which is what I would recommend if the CSS doesn't work out. There's just somethings CSS can't do. :/

Comment: Yeah thanks, I'll guess just on ready() I'll call the javascript to set the height dynamically. Do you know what function to use then on resize of window, to keep the same effect?

Comment: @Belov you should use `<body onresize="myFunction()">` The only other stuff I could find on resizeing tables is the columns you could look into this js **Demo:** http://bz.var.ru/comp/web/resizable.html **JS:** http://bz.var.ru/comp/web/resizable-tables.js